# Geofencing procedure

Tags: android, geofencing

How does geofencing works? I mean I just need two GPS coordinates (user's and target's GPS coordinates) and radius, then find distance between of them and if distance is less than or equal to radius then person is in geofence . Or there is more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's pretty much it.  There's probably some smoothing algorithms (to protect against bad readings causing a jump in a person's location),but its pretty much a distance check between two coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

The above solution work fine if we have a circular geofence, But if we have a geofence in a polygon shape, then we have to check if the user's location is within the boundry of the polygon.
There are many ways to do so
1. Google apis (if we are looking for android development).
2. Here map ( if we are going to expose rest apis, it is paid service).
3. Openmap provide library which can be used to create rest back end points . (free)